# ANTLR 4.5: line 1:22 mismatched input 'randomly' expecting DIRECTION

Tags: java, antlr4

The following grammar does not work properly with Antlr4.5 and Java 1.8.45 (IDE: IntelliJ Ultimate 14.1.4):

```
grammar PlayerAIShots;
file : row row EOF ;
row : START (randomshot)? SPACE direction Dot (LineBreak | EOF);

randomshot: RANDOM ;
direction : DIRECTION ;

RANDOM : 'randomly' ;
DIRECTION : ('to the left'|'to the right'|'central') ;
START : 'The opponent shoots' ;
SPACE : ' ' ;
Dot : '.' ;

// line break
LineBreak : '\r'?'\n' | '\r';

WS : [\t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip tabs, newlines
```

Letting the generated lexer and parser being evaluated results to:

> line 1:22 mismatched input 'randomly' expecting DIRECTION

In the used data (text file) the second line was properly processed, but as in the above stated error message not the first one. Here is the text file being used:

```
The opponent shoots randomly to the left.
The opponent shoots to the right.
```

Removing those SPACE within the definition of "row" the error does not occur. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line of your input is wrong. You didn't specify that you require space between `START` and `randomshot` like this

```
row : START (SPACE randomshot)? SPACE direction Dot (LineBreak | EOF);
```

When you remove 'SPACE' from 'row' definition you will get even more errors

```
line 1:19 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'randomly', DIRECTION}
line 1:28 extraneous input ' ' expecting DIRECTION
line 2:19 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'randomly', DIRECTION}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I put a space between 'START' and 'randomshot' I am getting: line 2:22 missing ' ' at 'to the right'. I think because the double 'SPACE'. If I remove the second 'SPACE' in front of direction I am getting another error: line 1:30 extraneous input ' ' expecting DIRECTION.

Comment: Yep it's becouse double SPACE, I added example how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries that is what really matched desired behaviour:

```
row : START SPACE (RANDOM)? (SPACE)? direction Dot (LineBreak | EOF);
```

Comment: I don't think it's proper solution. You allow double space between `START` and direction. Think about following input: `The opponent shoots  to the right.`

Comment: You are right, but the second "SPACE" could be there or not as it is stated this way: (SPACE)? (one or none). It works, but your solution above is much more proper. Thank you.